# Write scripts as stream-filters or parameter-only tools?

Tags: shell, utilities, filter

I'm writing a set of shell helper scripts - a kind of toolbox for simple data/text_files processing.

In it there will be some simple tools like, for example: `dateToTimestamp` or `showParagraphHeads`.

My question is:

**Should I write them as stream-filters or parameter-only tools?**

---

Let me explain it shortly. Some standard shell tools are obviously a stream-filters like `awk`, `sed` or lets say `tr` or `sort`, but others work only with parameters like `date` (this is setter/getter, but anyway).

`showParagraphHeads`:

So now, if I write a script that shows first line of every block of text (short line in awk/sed though) the answer is obvious because I need some multiline-stream/file to do that.

`dateToTimestamp`:

But if I write something that converts date from - say - YMDhms to timestamp then **it can be done as a stream-filter but also as a parameter-only tool** (similar to `date`) with usage like:
`dateToTimestamp DATE_IN_YMDhms`

---

Now, both ways have their pros and cons. Sometimes it's easier to just use pipe and use my stream filter. Another time I have more complex data and need to use `awk {system()}` on some column then it's easier to use parameter-based tool.

---

I know this is a general question, but maybe you know some convention or guidelines that maybe exist somewhere in *nix world.

Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that programs like `cat`, `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `sort`, ```wc```, etc., will read from files whose names are given on the command line, and will read from standard input if no files are specified.  I believe that’s a good model, in general — but ultimately one should think about what makes the most sense for each command.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Origin) is to "write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.", or to use stream-filters.

That said, how do you want (or need) to use the tools?

Let the answer to that question answer your question on a tool-by-tool basis, since another part of the Unix philosophy is that a functionally simple program with a simple implementation is better than a program that behaves consistently with other programs.

So, to pull from your example, if a utility to convert date formats is really simple if it accepts parameters, then only accept parameters if that meets your needs.